# Make text stick to top of screen, even when moving camera

Tags: game-development, haxe, haxeflixel, flixel

I am learning Haxe Flixel. I have a text that I want to stick to the top of the screen. I couldn't find anything in the API. How can I make a textObject stick even when camera centered around player is moving?

Similarly. How can I set up lower bounds of the screen, to make camera not have the radius around my player, and have the lower bound at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `scrollFactor`

```
object.scrollFactor.set(0, 0);
```

https://snippets.haxeflixel.com/camera/scrollfactor/